# How do I send ${} variables when in a gsp view to a template model?

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm working with a template that looks like this

```
<g:render template="templateName" model="[t:t, s:s, domainClass: domainInstance]"/>
```

I'm not sure of the terminology I should use but the above "domainInstance" needs to be replaced with something in the order of

```
${Adomainclass.list([max:1])}
```

I've tried surrounding it with single quotes and various other things I can't figure out how to satisfy the model.

Any tips here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dollar-currly-braces should be in the beginning of the model definition.

```
<g:render template="templateName" model="${[t:t, s:s, domainClass: Adomainclass.list([max:1])]}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not true.  When using the model you DO NOT need `${}`  `<g:render template="templateName" model="[t:t, s:s, domainClass: Adomainclass.list([max:1])]"/>` is perfectly fine.

Comment: might be :) But this way my IDE marks it as a code inclusion, not just plain xml.

Comment: Ahh... got it. No worries - you got it to work for the OP and that's the whole point!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing import statement in gsp:

```
<%@page import="Adomainclass"%>

<g:set var="instances" value="${Adomainclass.list([max:1])}" />

<g:render template="templateName" model="['t':t, 's':s, 'domainClass':instances]"/>
```